# Bayesian account for maximum likelihood estimate over infinite parameter space

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood

Suppose I have some samples $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ from $\mathcal{N}(\mu, 1)$ for unknown $\mu$. Then the maximum likelihood estimate for $\mu$ is just $\overline x = \frac1n \sum x_i$. Ideally, we can find a proper prior for $\mu$ such that after Bayesian update on all samples, the posterior density at $\overline x$ is the largest. However, this seems to require a flat prior on $(-\infty, \infty)$, which is not possible.

Assuming that Bayesian interpretation of probability is "correct", this seems to suggest that MLE will have suboptimal performance by not being fully aligned with Bayesian inference. However, given that MLE does work well in practice, there should be some way to account for its empirical success.

Comment: One way to say this is that you _always_ know _something_ about $\mu$ and the analysis benefits from making use of that knowledge.

Comment: Why do you want both a proper prior and matching with the MLE? A proper prior would be concentrated around some part of the real line, and the Bayesian posterior distribution would take that into account.  An improper flat conjugate prior for $\mu$ would give a posterior distribution for $\mu$ of $\mathcal N(\bar x, \frac1n)$, which is proper and centred where you want it to be.  If you think it wrong to use an improper prior, then it is equally wrong to use the MLE.